# Kth smallest element in unsorted array Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to find kth smallest element by recursion in unsorted array. I shouldn't use .sort() method. I will give you my code. What I am missing?

```
def findkth(lst,k):
    
    smaller = []
    larger = []
    pivot =lst[0] #choose pivot and create smaller and larger list based on pivot

    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        if pivot>=lst[i]:
            smaller.append(lst[i])
        else:
            larger.append(lst[i])
    print(smaller,"small",len(smaller))
    print(larger,"larger",len(larger))

    if len(smaller)<=k:# if length of smaller list is smaller then k then the number is I am looking is in the smaller list
        return findkth(smaller,k)
    elif len(smaller) == k-1: # if length of smaller list is 1 less then k then pivot is kth smallest one 
        return (pivot,"the char")
    else: # if first 2 conditions false then number is in the larger list
        return findkth(larger,k) 

mylst= [8,15,6,13,2,7,12,5,9,10]
print(findkth(mylst,3))
```

Comment: `elif len(smaller) == k-1` - this branch will never be followed, because if its condition is true, then `if len(smaller)<=k` will always be true as well.

Comment: @MrSmith42 maybe he is practicing on recursion

Comment: @MrSmith42 And how would you do that? I would have used Quickselect or a heap algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are all in this section of your code:

```
    if len(smaller)<=k:# if length of smaller list is smaller then k then the number is I am looking is in the smaller list
        return findkth(smaller,k)
    elif len(smaller) == k-1: # if length of smaller list is 1 less then k then pivot is kth smallest one 
        return (pivot,"the char")
    else: # if first 2 conditions false then number is in the larger list
        return findkth(larger,k)
```

The issues:

- The second `if` block will never be entered, because when `len(smaller) == k-1` is true, the *first* `if` block will be entered.
- The first code comment does not reflect correct reasoning. If the length of the smaller list is smaller than `k`, then surely the element you look for is **not** in that list. The condition should be `>=k`
- The final block executes the algorithm on `larger`, but still passes `k` as position. This cannot be right, because there are already `len(smaller)` values and the pivot that are all to be counted. For instance, if `k` is 5 and `len(smaller)` is 3, then -- together with the pivot -- we know that the 4 smallest values are not in `larger`. So in `larger` we should look with `k` equal to 1, not 5. Only that way we will find the *overall* 5th value.
- Not a problem, but I don't see why you would return "the char" joined into a tuple with the found value.

Here is a correction of that `if` structure:

```
    if len(smaller) >= k:  # We are sure the searched value is in `smaller`
        return findkth(smaller, k)
    elif len(smaller) == k - 1:
        return pivot
    else: # We reduce k to account for all values in `smaller` AND the pivot
        return findkth(larger, k - len(smaller) - 1)
```

With this change your code will work, assuming `k` is a valid argument (and not greater than the length of the input, or 0 or negative, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are properly using recursion because you are not defining a base step, and that's why your code gives multiple outputs, one for each step, which shouldn't happen. If I correctly understood the task, if the output of

```
mylst= [8,15,6,13,2,7,12,5,9,10]
print(findkth(mylst,3))
```

should be `6`, since 6 is the 3rd smallest number in `mylst`. That's why I don't understand why you also print the whole `smaller` and `larger` lists. However, I wrote this function that uses recursion and does your task. The work is carried out by a recursive function that takes  the `smaller` list as parameter, since you need to keep track of it during the recursion because it tells you what the smallest numbers are so far.

I used the `max` function for fastly finding the maximum value in the `smaller` list, I don't know if that's OK but if it's not it can be replaced by an other recursive function that finds the maximum element in a list.

```
def findkth_recursive(lst,k, smaller):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return max(smaller)
    else:
        pivot = lst[0]
        if len(smaller) < k:
            smaller.append(pivot)
        else:
            if pivot < max(smaller):
                for i in range (len(smaller)):
                    if smaller[i] == max(smaller):
                        smaller[i] = pivot
                        break      # Added after editing the answer
    return findkth_recursive(lst[1:], k, smaller)

def findkth(mylst, k):
   return findkth_recursive(mylst, k, [])

print(findkth(mylst, 3))
```

```
Output: 6
```

EDIT: There was a mistake in the original answer, I fixed it by adding a `break`

Comment: My bad. I edited the answer and the function. Thank you @slothrop for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You can find smallest Kth term using this:-

```
    def sort_list_find_Kth(list, K):
        new_list = []
        while list:
            minimum = list[0]  # arbitrary number in list
            for x in list:
                if x < minimum:
                    minimum = x
            new_list.append(minimum)
            list.remove(minimum)
        return print(f"The {K}th smallest term in {list} is {new_list[K]}")


mylist = [8, 15, 6, 13, 2, 7, 12, 5, 9, 10]
sort_list_find_Kth(mylist, K=int(input("Enter the Kth term: ")))
```

If you want for both smallest and largest Kth Term in the given list:-

```
data_list = [8, 15, 6, 13, 2, 7, 12, 5, 9, 10]
# to find the Kth smaller or larger element from the unnsorted list


def sort_list(list):
    new_list = []
    while data_list:
        minimum = data_list[0]  # arbitrary number in list
        for x in data_list:
            if x < minimum:
                minimum = x
        new_list.append(minimum)
        data_list.remove(minimum)
    return new_list


sorted_list = sort_list(data_list)
Kth = int(input("Enter the Kth term to find: "))
how_to_sort = input(
    f"You want to find Smallest or largest {Kth} th Term:  ").lower()

if how_to_sort == "smallest":
    print(
        f"Your {Kth} smallest is {sorted_list[Kth]} in the given array of {data_list}")

elif how_to_sort == "largest":
    desending_order_list = sorted_list[::-1]
    print(
        f"Your {Kth} smallest is {desending_order_list[Kth]} in the array of {data_list}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically correct:

```
import heapq

def findkth(lst, k):
    return heapq.nsmallest(k, lst)[-1]

mylst = [8,15,6,13,2,7,12,5,9,10]
print(findkth(mylst, 3))
# => 6
```

Look, no `.sort`!

Joking aside, while likely not what whoever gave you the task is looking for, this is what you'd do in real world, in two cases: when the list is relatively small, or when the list changes and you are repeatedly looking for the k-th smallest element. Otherwise you'd just use `.sort`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, "What's wrong here" --

```
else: # if first 2 conditions false then number is in the larger list
    return findkth(larger,k)
```

The line above is the problem. You need to subtract the smaller elements in the smaller list.

```
return findkth(larger, k - len(smaller)
```

E.g., if there are k-1 items in smaller, then the k'ths smallest item in the whole list is the smallest item in the larger list.

Also, your first two conditions should be switched so the branch that finds the k'th smallest element can be reached.